# Win32: LoadIcon vs LoadImage

Tags: winapi

Everything that I read tells me that Win32 API `LoadIcon` is out of date; instead, I should be using `LoadImage`.  However, I am confused by the [official `LoadImage` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew):

> If the *hinst* parameter is `NULL` and the *fuLoad* parameter omits the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` value, the *lpszName* specifies the OEM image to load. The OEM image identifiers are defined in Winuser.h and have the following prefixes.
>
> | Prefix | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | OBM_ | OEM bitmaps |
> | OIC_ | OEM icons |
> | OCR_ | OEM cursors |

So vague!  No specifics provided -- that I can find.

Are there official docs to translate `IDI_` constants for `LoadIcon()` into `OIC_` constants for `LoadImage()`?  I only have access to MinGW-W64 on Linux, instead of the official Win32 SDK.  Google-fu fails me here.

Example translation (after searching MinGW-W64 headers on Linux):

```
#define IDI_QUESTION 32514
#define OIC_QUES 32514
```

Comment: Just pass an IDI_ identifier to LoadImage(), the values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) said in the following,

> To pass these constants to the **LoadImage** function, use the
> [MAKEINTRESOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcea) macro. For example, to load the OCR_NORMAL cursor,
> pass MAKEINTRESOURCE(OCR_NORMAL) as the lpszName parameter, NULL as
> the hinst parameter, and LR_SHARED as one of the flags to the fuLoad
> parameter.

```
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEA(i) ((LPSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i))))
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEW(i) ((LPWSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i))))
#ifdef UNICODE
#define MAKEINTRESOURCE  MAKEINTRESOURCEW
#else
#define MAKEINTRESOURCE  MAKEINTRESOURCEA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

In consideration of *MAKEINTRESOURCE*, It Converts an integer value to a resource type compatible with the resource-management functions. Here is @HansPassant said [the values are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76283111/win32-loadicon-vs-loadimage#comment134520090_76283111).